# AutoHotKey script to stay pressed a ALT button of keyboard

Tags: autohotkey

and if possible a command to turn on/off this pressed button.
I just want that alt button stay pressed as time as i need, like forever when it been turned on.

Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 1):

This will press ALT down when you press F2 and toggle it off when you press F2 agian

```
Down := false

*F2::
Down := !Down
If Down
    Send {ALT Down}
else
    Send {ALT Up}
return
```

Comment: if i want to edit the button what i need to do ? like change it to the C bottun ?

Comment: Do you want to use c to toggle alt or do you want to toggle c?

Comment: we can keep the F2, i just want to change de ALT to other button to be holded like change ALT to C or F7 for exemple.

Comment: Then just replace "ALT" with "c"... Please remember that this will not make the key auto-repert, only set its state to down, this may not be what you need, but its what you asked for :)